# Remove superfluous `andi ..., 0xff` instruction from inline assembly when outputting an `i8`

Tags: rust, mips, inline-assembly

I have the following function using inline assembly, targeting `mipsel-unknown-linux-gnu`:

```rust
#![feature(asm)]

#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn f(ptr: u32) {
    let value: i8;
    asm!(
        "lb $v0, ($a0)",
        in("$4") ptr,
        out("$2") value,
    );
    asm!(
        "sb $v0, ($a0)",
        in("$4") ptr,
        in("$2") value,
    );
}
```

I expected this to compile into the following:

```
lb $v0, ($a0)
sb $v0, ($a0)
jr $ra
nop
```

Note: In this example, it's possible the compiler reorders the store instruction to after the jump to use the delay slot, but in my actual use case, I return via an `asm` block, so this is not a worry. Given this I expected the assembly above exactly.

Instead, what I got was:

```
00000000 <f>:
   0:   80820000        lb      v0,0(a0)
   4:   304200ff        andi    v0,v0,0xff
   8:   a0820000        sb      v0,0(a0)
   c:   03e00008        jr      ra
  10:   00000000        nop
```

The compiler seems to not have trusted me that the output is an `i8` and inserted an `andi $v0, 0xff` instruction there.

I need to produce the assembly I specified above exactly, so I'd like to get rid of the `andi` instruction, while keeping the type of `value` i8.

My use case for this is that I want to produce an exact assembly output from this function, while being able to later fork it and add rust code that interacts with the existing assembly code to extend the function. For this I'd like `value`'s type to be properly described as an `i8` in the rust side.

#### Edit

Looking at the llvm-ir generated by rust, the `andi` instruction seems to have been added by `rustc`, not llvm.

```
; Function Attrs: nonlazybind uwtable
define void @f(i32 %ptr) unnamed_addr #0 {
start:
  %0 = tail call i32 asm sideeffect alignstack "lbu $$v0, ($$a0)", "=&{$2},{$4},~{memory}"(i32 %ptr) #1, !srcloc !2
  %1 = and i32 %0, 255   # <--------- Over here
  tail call void asm sideeffect alignstack "sb $$v0, ($$a0)", "{$4},{$2},~{memory}"(i32 %ptr, i32 %1) #1, !srcloc !3
  ret void
}
```

There is also no mention of an `i8`, so I'm not quite sure what `rustc` is doing here.

Comment: *I return via an `asm` block* - I assume this is in a `naked` function or equivalent, or you have a Rust equivalent of `__builtin_unreachable()` after the asm statement so the compiler knows about that...  If you're returning manually, that means your function can't inline so you can generally get equivalent performance from writing the whole thing in stand-alone asm.  But that's separate from this question, which is interesting for other use-cases.  MIPS compilers need to keep most things sign-extended I think, for the ABI and maybe even a few instructions, IIRC, other than `addu`/`subu`.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'd forgotten about sign extension, but I believe `lb` should sign extend, right? I also tried the code with `u8` (and `lbu`) and it still contains the `andi` instruction, so I believe there's something else at play here.

Comment: Yes, that's right, your asm template produces output already sign-extended to fill a register.  But of course LLVM doesn't know that, all it knows is that you told it the output operand is a an `i8`, which probably means that the upper bit of the register may hold random garbage. (IDK why it would choose to zero-extend; maybe it realizes it can do that more cheaply than sext without later MIPS32 instructions, and its ok because it's only consumed by another asm i8 input?)

Comment: So probably you could tell it the output is an `i32`.  That would defeat later optimizations that depend on value-range analysis knowing it's within [-128..127], for which you'd need some other builtin assume.  (Like GNU C `if(x < -128) __builtin_unreachable();`, although some compilers like ICC for x86 actually emit code to check and branch to actual garbage.)

Comment: @PeterCordes You gave me the idea to check the llvm-ir and it seems that `rustc` is the one telling llvm-ir to `and` it, see the question edit.

Comment: Do you have a godbolt link for your code?  I tried putting it up with rustc nightly `-O --target mipsel-unknown-linux-gnu`, but it errors with "error[E0658]: inline assembly is not stable yet on this architecture".  https://godbolt.org/z/Kznc3xYM6

Comment: @PeterCordes Turns out I haven't updated my rustc in a bit, and in the meantime they've locked inline assembly for mips behind another feature: `asm_experimental_arch`. Here is a proper godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/z/9zKd6PbTz

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/vT1TT4Th9 Turns out it needed `#![feature(asm_experimental_arch)]
`.  With that, your code produced an extra `move $2, $4`, because you had the register numbers for `$v0` and `$a0` backwards.  (http://www.cs.uwm.edu/classes/cs315/Bacon/Lecture/HTML/ch05s03.html) In my link, I swapped them. And I tried `i32`, that does work.  You could assign the `i32` to an `i8` afterward, for later use by Rust code.

Comment: @PeterCordes Oops, my bad, I had them in the correct order locally, just somehow messed up when posting, I'll edit the question. But unfortunately, re-assigning the i32 to a i8 still includes the `andi` instruction.

Comment: BTW, it's always been a problem to write inline asm that tells the compiler the value is already correctly extended to a full reg, but has a limited value-range.  (e.g. for x86-64 `popcnt`.  GCC even has problems with that with its own built-in functions, but that's a totally separate thing.)  Anyway, giving the store the  `i32` and just keeping the i8 around for pure Rust usage doesn't generate an extra `and` https://godbolt.org/z/sxd7Wx4xj, although that doesn't tell us much because the i8 value is unused.

Comment: @PeterCordes Oh wow, you're right that compilers have problems with this. I tried modifying the llvm-ir to remove the andi instruction and change the type to `i8` and `llc` just hard crashed. I guess for now I'll have to go with your suggestion of declaring 32-bit and casting it to `i8` whenever I use it on the rust side.